# What is this phusion wrapper script doing?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, phusion-passenger

```
if [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/environments/ree-1.8.7-2010.02" ]] ; then
  source "/usr/local/rvm/environments/ree-1.8.7-2010.02"
  exec ruby "$@"
else
  echo "ERROR: Missing RVM environment file: '/usr/local/rvm/environments/ree-1.8.7-2010.02'" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

What does '`-s`' do?

And what is '`>&2`' doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -s [tests](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) that the file exists and has a size greater than 0.

The >&2 is [directing](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) the output of the echo command to stderr which is file descriptor 2.

Comment: so if the file exists, the source is loading it up in memory?

Comment: The ree-1.8.7-2010.02 script is setting up the environment for the ruby "$@" command. Normally when you run a script it is executed in a sub-process and any environment variables created are lost when the script exits. The source command executes the commands in ree-1.8.7-2010.02 within the current shell so the environment etc are available to the ruby "$@" command.

Comment: This is a wrapper script that is referenced inside of my nginx.conf file, so I need to set my GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME so my rails app uses those, wondering if this script is the right place.